# Dynamic value from object TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have simple object

```
const trans = {
a: {
    valueA: 'a'
},
b: {
    valueB: 'b'
}
```

};

and when i wanna grab a dynamic value of trans.a.valueA I can do:

```
console.log(trans['a'].valueA);
```

but when I try wrapp this in function like this:

```
function foo(key:keyof typeof trans) {
return trans[key];
}
```

and try get a value of 'valueA'

```
console.log(foo('a').valueA);
```

I get a TS error

```
Property 'valueA' does not exist on type '{ valueB: string; }'
```

So How I can get dynamic value from object by function?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way:

```js
  function foo(key:keyof typeof trans) {
    return trans[key] as any;
  }
```

Comment: yeah I know this way, but it is dirty and I lose hints in editor.. This way do JavaScript from TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `keyof typeof trans` is equal to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) `"a" | "b"`.

All the compiler knows about `foo()` is that it takes a value of type `"a" | "b"`, and returns the type of indexing into `trans` with that.

Thus the output type of `foo()` is going to be `(typeof trans)["a" | "b"])`

which is the same as `(typeof trans)["a"] | (typeof trans)["b"]`, or

`{ valueA: string; } | { valueB: string; }`, which is itself a union.

And if I give you a value of that type, you can't just get its `valueA` property without making sure that it has one first.  That's the warning you're getting... the compiler is telling you that the output of `foo()` *might* be `{ valueB: string; }` which doesn't have a `valueA` property.

So you could check it yourself to make the compiler happy:

```
const fooA = foo("a");
if ("valueA" in fooA) {
    // fooA is now known to be {valueA: string}
    console.log(fooA.valueA) // okay now
} else {
    // fooA is now known to be {valueB: string}
    throw new Error("THE WORLD MAKES NO SENSE");
}
```

Fine, everything is good now and we're all set here, right?  Just kidding.

---

You're probably objecting that *of course* if you pass `"a"` into `foo()` that the output will *have to be* of type `{valueA: string}`.  And you're right, but the compiler doesn't automatically try to verify that.  The way to get the behavior you're looking for is to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function:

```
function foo<K extends keyof typeof trans>(key: K) {
    return trans[key];
}
```

In that, `K` is a *generic* type which must be a subtype of `"a" | "b"`.  In practice, that means that `K` can be either the type `"a"`, or it can be the type `"b"`, or it can possibly be the full union `"a" | "b"`.  The return type of `foo()` is now `(typeof trans)[K]`, a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

When you call `foo()` now, the compiler will try to *infer* the *narrowest* type for `K` that it can, and the return type will be the narrowest type it can be as a result.

```
// K inferred as "a":
const fooA = foo("a");
// fooA is of type (typeof trans)["a"], which is {valueA: string}
console.log(fooA.valueA); // okay
```

And for `"b"`,

```
// K inferred as "b":
const fooB = foo("b");
// fooB is of type (typeof trans)["b"], which is {valueB: string}
console.log(fooB.valueB); // okay
```

And, to demonstrate a legitimate need for checking union types:

```
// K inferred as the full union "a" | "b" 
const fooAB = foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"); 
// fooAB is of type (typeof trans)["a" | "b"], the wide type from before
// better check it ourselves:
if ("valueA" in fooAB) {
    // fooAB is now known to be {valueA: string}
    console.log(fooAB.valueA) // okay
} else {
    // fooAB is now known to be {valueB: string}
    console.log(fooAB.valueB) // okay
}
```

Whew.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect answer of course works like a rock!